# How to pass a value from HTML to Node JS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I tried to get a value from a HTML table to Node JS. I tried like following,

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
   {{#images}}
   <tr>
       <td><a href="/deleteImage" class="btn btn-danger" title="Clear All">X</a><label value={{imgURL}} name="imageID">{{imgURL}}</label>
       </td>
       <td><img src={{imgURL}} alt="Mountain View" style="width:228px;height:340px"></td>
   </tr>
   {{/images}}
</table>
```

**app.js**

```
app.get('/deleteImage', function (req, res) {
  images.removeImage(req.body.imageID, function (err, result) {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    images.getImages(function (err, images) {
        if (err) return res.json(err);
        var msg = 'Deleted ' + result.affectedRows + ' rows.';
        res.render('delete_image.html', {images: images, msg: msg});
    });
  });
});
```

I tried to read the `imageID` from the HTML like above. But It's `undefined`. How can I fix this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: A common way to pass parameters to the server are by putting parameters on the URL such as `/deleteImage?id=123`.  Then on your node server, you can get the `id=123` out of the URL.  If you don't want to actually load a new web page when sending the request, then make the request an Ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
<a href="/deleteImage?imageID={{imgURL}}" class="btn btn-danger" title="Clear All">X</a>
```

and use req.query.imageID instead